# Can't override Sass variables in node_modules using custom Materialize Sass files and GruntJs

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, materialize

I recently started playing with Materialize because I wanted to use something other than Bootstrap.

I'm used to using LESS and compiling it with Grunt and the way that was set up is like this:

The grunt file would import a file called custom.less.

This file will import bootstrap-import.less which will import all the Bootstrap LESS files from the node_modules folder which I got with NPM materialize-css.

After that, it will import the same file structure in my custom folder where I can override variables and make custom changes to the original bootstrap CSS.

So with LESS, I can import the original variables.less file and after that, I can include my own variables.less file where I can override for example @brand-primary color.

But when I try doing this with SASS and materialize, it keeps using the variables that were set first. It doesn't use the variables that were set in my own variables file which defines the same variables with different colors.

Please let me know if this doesn't make sense?

```
MyWebsite/
  |--node_modules
  |  |--materialize-css
  |     |--sass
  |        |--components/all sass files here
  |--src/
  |  |--sass/components/my custom sass files
  |
  |--gruntfile.js // Imports sass files from node modules
  |               // Imports my custom sass files including variables.sass
  |               // to override the variables file in node_modules
  |
  |
  |--index.html
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override materializecss sass variables in vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458439/how-to-override-materializecss-sass-variables-in-vue)

Answer (score 0):

I would import materialize from within your sass files.

So in your `src/sass/main.scss`

```
// Variables;
@import "../../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/componenets/variables";

// Change your variables here
$primary-color: blue;

// Reset
@import "../../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/componenets/normalize";

// components
@import "../../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/componenets/global";
```

Have a look at the [`materialize.scss`](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/sass/materialize.scss) how they import their components.

Comment: So would you do an npm install and then copy all the Sass files from the node_modules folder into your own sass folder?

Comment: Not *copy* but [**import**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import).
This means you can over write the variables the other components use.
(I edited my code above a bit.)